# Python: how to load (substitute) attribute name from list

Tags: python

#### I would like to improve this piece of code:

```
class opt_variable:

       pass

var = opt_variable

List = ["name", "value"]

var.List[0] = "XXX"
```

I got this message:

```
AttributeError: type object 'opt_variable' has no attribute 'List'
```

I would like to use attribute name called from the previously defined list.

Comment: When posting broken code because you don't know how to achieve *exactly* what you need, it's helpful to also provide an example of code that works that does kind of what you want. (E.g. I'm *guessing* in this case you want to end up with the equivalent of `var.name = "XXX"` - your question would be clearer if it didn't involve the "guessing" part.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use setattr to add attributes to objects.

```
setattr(var, List[0], "XXX")
```